# How to define whether a sample falls within a 95% confidence interval in PCA model?

Tags: r, pca, ellipse

I am creating a PCA model in R and would like to know whether my sample (red) is within or outside the ellipse. Could you maybe help me how to do that?

At the moment I am using Mahalanobis distance, but in some cases it predicts wrongly, since it is in a multivariate space and here I use only two principal components.

The code i am using to create a plot:

```
  plt <- autoplot(
      pcaAroma, 
      data = keepRows,
      colour = 'Woi',
      frame.type = 'norm',
      type = "cairo",
      res=100,
      size = 4
  )
```

[image]

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. How is the ellipse defined? Give an example where your method fails.

Comment: could not find a reasonable way to upload the data, so will leave it AS IS for now.